# CSS3 - Images doesn't show in IE whilst using CSS3 transitions

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, transition

CSS3 - Images doesn't show in IE whilst using CSS3 transitions. I do not mind if the animation does not work in IE, but I would at least want the images to display normally in IE. Here is my code below:

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="bg">
    <img class="fadeIn fadeIn-3s fadeIn-Delay-3s" src="images/about-phil.jpg" alt="Phil Davel About Us Background Image">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fadeIn {
opacity:0;
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
margin-bottom: -10px;
```

}

```
.fadeIn-3s {
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s;
    -o-animation-duration:3s;
    animation-duration:3s;
}

.fadeIn-Delay-3s {
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -moz-animation-delay:1s;
    -o-animation-delay:1s;
    animation-delay:1s;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Did you try it giving some dimensions to the image first?

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Animation is not supported in IE.

You can use a conditional statement in your HTML to include an extra CSS file if the user is using IE. By doing so you can display your images differently for IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```